# Python Dictionary or Alternative

Tags: python, dictionary

For instance,

```
if dict['sample']:
    //append values to dict['sample']
else:
    // assign new key to the python dictionary
```

If dict['sample'] is empty, Python will throw errors. Does anyone know a better way to check on this?

All I want is something like that, I will have list of data, let's say a,a,b,c,g,g,g,g,g.

So, I want python dictionary to append the values of two a,a to dict['a'], and g,g,g,g,g to dict['g'] and so the rest as dict['b'] etc. A for loop will be executed to loop through the data of a,a,b,c,g,g,g,g,g.

I hope I've made my question clear. Any idea? Preferably, if Python's dictionary has a way to check existing key.

**EDIT**

Credit goes to @Paul McGuire. I've figured out the exact solution I wanted based on @Paul McGuire's answer. As shown below:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Test:
   def __init__(self, a,b):
       self.a=a
       self.b=b

data = []
data.append(Test(a=4,b=6))
data.append(Test(a=1,b=2))
data.append(Test(a=1,b=3))
data.append(Test(a=2,b=2))
data.append(Test(a=3,b=2))
data.append(Test(a=4,b=5))
data.append(Test(a=4,b=2))
data.append(Test(a=1,b=2))
data.append(Test(a=5,b=9))
data.append(Test(a=4,b=7))

dd = defaultdict(list)
for c in data:
    dd[c.a].append(c.b)
print dd
```

Comment: Another learning opportunity - the *namedtuple*.  Replace your Test class (which should extend `object`, BTW), with this: `Test=namedtuple("Test", "a b")`, add `namedtuple` to your import from the collections module, and leave everything else alone. `namedtuples` are handy for these simple struct-like classes, plus they are immutable so can be used as proper dict keys and set values.

Comment: Thanks again for the knowledge. Above was just an example I've written. I was supposed to get data from server side and returned GQL Query object. But your suggestion certainly helpful for future needs. Thanks again ! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The old approaches of "if key in dict" or "dict.get" or "dict.setdefault" should all be set aside in favor of the now standard `defaultdict`:

```
data = "aabcggggg"

from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for c in data:
    dd[c].append(c)
print dd
```

defaultdict takes care of the checking for key existence for you, all your code has to do is 1) define a factory function or class for the defaultdict to use to initialize a new key entry (in this case, `defaultdict(list)`), and 2) define what to do with each key (`dd[c].append(c)`).  Clean, simple, no clutter.

In your particular example, you could actually use `itertools.groupby`, since the groups of letters are all contiguous for each grouping value.  `groupby` returns an iterator of tuples, each tuple containing the current key value and an iterator of the matching values.  The following code works by converting each tuple's list-of-values-iterator to an actual list (in `list(v)`), and passing the sequence of key-valuelist tuples to the dict constructor.

```
from itertools import groupby
print dict((k,list(v)) for k,v in groupby(data))
```

prints:

```
{'a': ['a', 'a'], 'c': ['c'], 'b': ['b'], 'g': ['g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g']}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paul McGuire, I didn't describe in details the code I was trying to write. I summarized it as my question above. I was actually going to loop through objects rather than just alphabets.

But, still your answer provides extra knowledge to many people. Appreciate that very much ! Thanks a lot ! ;)

Comment: BTW @Paul McGuire, I just wonder any significant difference between yours and 'if key in dict' ? Because for my situation, once same key detected, I would need to perform a different action.

If this has impact on better performance, I would like to accept your answer instead. However, I just wonder if it solves my case. I've edited my question.

Comment: Hi @Paul McGuire, I've accepted your answer as I've posted the latest solution based on your example which best fits the issue I was trying to solve. 

I've posted exact solution on my question. :)


But, still I hope you will explain a bit significant difference between yours and others as you have highlighted from your first statement 'The old approaches of "if key in dict" or "dict.get" or "dict.setdefault" should all be set aside in favor of the now standard defaultdict'

Comment: `dict.has_key`, `dict.get(key,[default])`, and `dict.setdefault` were crutches for this "if key not found, initialize with default value and then update" idiom, leftover from older versions of Python that did not have the current support that we have now for "in", or `__missing__`, or defaultdict. We need to move forward to the new ones, as they will continue to be enhanced and improved. For instance, the key-test-and-default-set logic in defaultdict is done compiled "C" machine code, so it will be faster and more efficient than the corresponding Python "if key not in dict: dict[key]=default.

Comment: defaultdict also has the benefit of being constructed with a factory method, not a default value. `dict.get(key,default)` *always* creates the default value, even if the key is already present and the default is not needed. Because defaultdict is created with a factory method, it only constructs default values when there is no matching key.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks so much for your sharing. I've understood so much more now. I'm glad that I've found the solution using your suggestion. Thanks a lot ! ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict.setdefault('sample', []).append(value)
```

second parameter of 'setdefault' method says what should be initial value if given key does not exist

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your values are lists.

```
if 'sample' in mydict:
    pass #whatever  
else: 
    mydict['sample'] = []
```

What you want to do is the following:

```
A = ['a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']

myDict = {}
for i in A:
    if i not in myDict: 
        myDict[i] = []
    myDict[i].append(i) 
print myDict
```

Comment: This works too. I've posted my own answer as to what I think the simplest solution that I wanted. But, decided to give credit to you as it works fine too your way. Thanks !

Comment: I understand why people voted my answer: even a newby(like me)understands what's going on by reading my simple code. But, while reading the other answers to this question I learnt about  defaultdict! Indeed, if I understand, it behaves like a subclass of a dictionary where I have overloaded the member function to get an item with a try (to get the item) except (do default). 
If you use your dictionary only as a dictionary of lists(and this is the behavior you desire all along the program)my solution is non-sense(since it requires a lot of code copy-paste)and the solution is the defaultdict!

Comment: I do believe an "if in" statement read more beautiful then using exceptions like I did just out of habit. Just wanted to tell :)

Comment: My bad that I didn't describe entirely my situation is as I thought my question was a summarized version of what I was trying to achieve.

The reason I wanted this was because I needed to loop through objects instead of really just alphabets. It's far more complex which was why I accepted this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Every dict key should contain a list. Am I right?

```
d = dict()
try:
    d['sample'].append(new_data)
except KeyError:
    d['sample'] = [new_data]
```

I believe this would work. By the way, you shouldn't use the name dict for a dictonary. dict is already used as a function.

## Edit1:

I'm not really sure I understand what you trying to do. Nor do I know if my solution is the best of those proposed. But is it this you are trying to do? It seems a little bit odd? Or do you want to count how many times every letter occur?

```
# Create a list named l.
l = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g','g']

# Create dictionary named d.
d = dict()

for i in l:
    try:
        d[i].append(i)
    except KeyError:
        d[i] = [i]
```

Comment: It helps a lot @Niclas Nilsson even though it didn't directly solve my problem but it helped me to figure out the solution with the except KeyError: . I overlooked on this apparently. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some very old python:

```
if not myDict.has_key(key):
    myDict[key]=[val]
else:
    myDict[key].append(val)
```

Recently the has_key has been deprecated in favor of `key in dict`
So nowadays, it would be:

```
if not key in myDict:
    myDict[key]=[val]
else:
    myDict[key].append(val)
```

Comment: Do not perpetuate this practice! has_key was deprecated many versions ago, in favor of "if key in myDict:".

Comment: recently? probably not too many people using Python 2.1 or older

Comment: Agreed, but in my defense, OP never mentioned which version of python.

Answer (score 0):

Credit should goes to @Niclas Nilsson even though his posted solution didn't really worked for what I wanted, however, it did help me figure out the solution that I wanted in the simplest form.

Still, I appreciate everyone's help here for extra knowledge and alternative ways of solving it. Thanks a lot.

Following achieved what I wanted in the simplest way without additional library imported etc:

```
r = {}

try:
    if r['new_data']:
       r['new_data'] = 'appending'
except KeyError:
    r['new_data'] = 'new value'

print r['new_data']
```

Comment: Thanks again dude. Really appreciate your help. Keep up the good work  ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution I wanted the most as shown below. Credit goes to @Paul McGuire

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Test:
   def __init__(self, a,b):
       self.a=a
       self.b=b

data = []
data.append(Test(a=4,b=6))
data.append(Test(a=1,b=2))
data.append(Test(a=1,b=3))
data.append(Test(a=2,b=2))
data.append(Test(a=3,b=2))
data.append(Test(a=4,b=5))
data.append(Test(a=4,b=2))
data.append(Test(a=1,b=2))
data.append(Test(a=5,b=9))
data.append(Test(a=4,b=7))

dd = defaultdict(list)
for c in data:
    dd[c.a].append(c.b)
print dd
```